# Java Cucumber DataTable Comparison using cucumber diff()

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber

I am using Cucumber diff for comparing the DataTables in Java. If a mismatch is found, it will throw a TableDiffException.

For example:

dataTable1.unorderedDiff(dataTable2)

I just wanted to know if there is any way to print only the mismatch column once the exception is thrown, as it is very difficult to compare both the data datables manually after logging, since the datatable size is quite huge(10 rows and 20 columns).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a pretty good exception:
For the Feature
    @DevTag
    Feature: basic test feature

```
Scenario: Scenario1
Given i do this
When i do that
|a|a|
|b|b|
|c|c|
Then i expect something
|a|a|
|b|c|
|c|c|
```

Then you will get the Exception:

```
cucumber.runtime.table.TableDiffException: Tables were not identical:
  | a | a |
- | b | b |
  | c | c |
+ | b | c |
```

But here is a way to change that:

```
try {
    one.unorderedDiff(two);
} catch (Tablee) {
    String s = e.toString();
    s.split("\n");
    for(String elem: s.split("\n")){
        if(elem.trim().startsWith("+")){
          System.out.println(elem);
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see, it is possible to catch that exception, then you can work with it. I split it to get every line, and then only print the wrong line.

If you want to, you can throw a new exception which only contains the message with the wrong line.

Does that help you? If not feel free to comment